# How to validate date format in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check if a given string is a valid .net date format.

so i have the following function that checks if the date format is correct

```
    public void IsValidDateFormat(string dateFormat)
    {
        var flag = true;
        try
        {
            DateTime.ParseExact(DateTime.Now.ToString(),
                dateFormat,
                System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            flag = false;
        }

       return flag;
    }
```

However, The method is not working as expected. For a valid date format also it returns false.

`dateFormat = ,,`  => returns false =>Passed
`dateFormat = someinvalidformat`  => returns false =>Passed
`dateFormat = MM/dd/yyyy`  => returns false => Not Passed

So `MM/dd/yyyy` is valid dateformat. But method returns false.

Is there a better way to check if given date format is valid .Net date format?

**Update 1**
I understand why method fails for `MM/dd/yyyy` or for other valid date formats. I am not asking why it fails. `MM/dd/yyyy` is just common valid date time format i am using here for example.
I am looking for a way to check if the given date format is valid .Net date format. So it could be any .Net date format.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.ToString()` returns `MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt`. Attempting `ParseExact` with `MM/dd/yyyy` will fail because the string is not in that format.

Comment: i know why it fails. i am looking for a way to validate date format

Comment: Use `ToShortDateString()` instead of `ToString()`. This will still cause your `MM/dd/yyyy` format to fail in months before October.

Comment: Use `DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()` then

Comment: Could you recycle the result? Apply your format and then tryParse the result and and compare that result to the DateTime.Now? including and excluding the time would be important. I don't have VS on this box to test it for you.

Comment: It's still unclear what you mean by a valid format string. Technically, `"MM yyyy MM yyyy H tt z"` is a valid format string. So is `"123123123123"`. It might not be meaningful, but it's valid.

Comment: Either specify a string constant with a date in the desired format or use `Parse` instead of `ParseExact`. Better yet: Use `TryParseExact`!

Comment: `TryParseExact` will not solve the issue. It just returns true or false instead of throwing exception.

Comment: @JonathonChase you are right `MM yyyy MM yyyy H tt z` is valid format. But above will return `false`

Comment: @LP13 The above will return false because it will only return true if the dateFormat is `"M/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss tt"`, since that's the format you're testing against.

Comment: `I am looking for a way to check if the given date format is valid .Net date format.` . From the given code, the question is more like: `I am looking for a way to check if the given date format is valid .Net date format that can parse DateTime.Now.ToString().`

Answer (score 3):

Since the format returned by `DateTime.ToString` does not match your format (it includes the time part), `ParseExact` fails.

Validate the format by using `public string ToString(string format, System.IFormatProvider provider)` instead

```
public bool IsValidDateFormat(string dateFormat)
{
    try {
        string s = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        return true;
    } catch {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Note that date/time formats that may seem not to be valid, can in fact be valid, as some non-format characters are just outputted as is. E.g.

```
DateTime.Now.ToString("abcdefg", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

results in `"abc27e6A.D."`. So it is in fact a valid date/time format, even if it does not make a lot of sense. You can enhance the quality of the test by trying to parse the resulting date string. This will eliminate a lot of nonsensical formats.

This test ...

```
Console.WriteLine(IsValidDateFormat(",,"));
Console.WriteLine(IsValidDateFormat("a"));
Console.WriteLine(IsValidDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss"));
Console.WriteLine(IsValidDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"));
Console.WriteLine(IsValidDateFormat("abcdefg"));
Console.ReadKey();
```

... prints

> False
>   False
>   True
>   True
>   False

Comment: this throws an exception for dateFormat "a"

Comment: @Matt.G, yes, you are right. Obviously `TryPareExact` throws when the format itself is invalid. I changed my answer.

Answer (score -1):

why not `TryParse()` or exact version? https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8

returns true if system can parse.

It does "the same" your method does.

Comment: `TryParse` does not take format. I am not validating date. i want to validate the dateformat